# How can I get the number of nodes of a Neo4j graph database from java and can we store and reuse graphdb from disk?

Tags: java, social-networking, neo4j, graph-databases

I just started looking at neo4j to use it for my social-network related project. During this I came across the following code:

```
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.M04/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing.java
```

While going through it (please refer to above link for code), I was struggling to know, how to get the total number of nodes added to a given `graphDb`. Is there any way to find it (total number of nodes) using `graphDb` or `nodeIndex` or `referenceIndex` or anything else? If yes, How?

I also need help to know, how to store the graphdb to any given path on disk? How to load this stored graphdb and perform operations on it like searching for a node/relationship etc?

(There are several files like *.db, *.id, *.keys etc.. created at given `DB_PATH` when above code is executed. What are all those files useful for? Does any of those files contain nodes created? if yes, how can we use them?)

How can we access this `graphDb` from web-interfaces like, Dashboard at `http://localhost:7474/webadmin/` or data at `http://localhost:7474/db/data/` ?

Please let me know in case you need any specific information to help me..

Thanks, Nitin.

Answer (score 5):

For getting started with Neo4j Embedded and the Java API see:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded.html

Getting correct counts of nodes and relationships:

```
IteratorUtil.count(GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllNodes())
IteratorUtil.count(GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllRelationships())
```

For accessing an embedded graph database with an integrated neo4j server, see
  http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-embedded.html

Answer (score 3):

Phewww! Those are a lot of questions for one entry...

To get the total number of nodes and relationships in your DB, use:

```
NodeManager nodeManager = ((GraphDatabaseAPI) graphDb).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(
            NodeManager.class);

long currentRelationships = nodeManager.getNumberOfIdsInUse(Relationship.class);
long currentNodes = nodeManager.getNumberOfIdsInUse(Node.class);
```

To change the path of the graph DB, simply pass the path to the GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase method. In the example you mentioned, you could simply set DB_PATH e.g. to `/home/youruser/neo4j`.

To access your DB with the webadmin, download neo4j, change the org.neo4j.server.database.location property in the file `conf/neo4j-server.properties` and point it to the path of your DB and launch the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot @James . About, `GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH )`, will this load the database if there is already present at given path? If not, How can we load it instead of creating a new one? And what are various files created at given path?  Can you refer me to any link where I can find such specific documentation/tutorial (except `http://docs.neo4j.org`)?

Comment: As we can see in code, there are 100 (+1 reference node) Nodes added to graphDb. But then, why a am I getting `currentRelationships=300` and `currentNodes=304` as output?

Comment: You're getting 304 nodes, because you ran the program three times... It's adding 101 nodes per run plus the one reference node = 304. ;-)